# Change phone number of contact with contacts_service in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

If i do the following:

```
widget.contact.phones.elementAt(1).value = "023492034902";
```

Flutter/Dart doesn't throw me an error, but the value is not changed to my defined String. I know how to edit the contacts name programmatically but as phones is an Iterable I don't know how to change a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the contact using this line of code?

```
await ContactsService.updateContact(contact);
```

I think it should change the contact from its identifier, so you just update the contact that already existed.

I got the code from the example here https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service

Comment: [You] think? Like, you're not really sure about it, éh?

Comment: I tried getting this to work, but actually the contacts service package has an issue with the updateContact method, which hasn't been fixed yet unfortunately.